# Problems with EntityFramework.HierarchyId

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, hierarchyid

I'm trying to use the `EntityFramework.HierarchyId` Nuget Package to add support for the `HierarchyId` datatype inside of EF 6, the problem is that everytime that I add the package and try to build the project, I get the following error:

> Error 3 The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

---

If I remove the package and reinstall the EF 6.1 the problem is gone.

This is what I have on my Web.config file:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6847f3395fc61b47" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

If I change the version to what the error says, the problem still stays:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your issues is conflict between `EF.HiearachyId` and `Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework` because it add reference with `'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`. Your problem can find at [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525080125/http://entityframework.codeplex.com:80/discussions/415185). You can fix it:

1. Reflect `Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll` and get code from it.
2. Create new project and paste code you copied.
3. Replace reference `Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework` with your new project.

I think that will resolve your problem.